# Job Queueing for remote connecting devices

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, web-services, sockets, http

Yes, the title is very broad, but that's what my problem is.  I don't know what to search for...  Geez, I don't even know what Tags to add to this post!

I'm wanting to create a service where a device checks into a remote server for any jobs that it is supposed to run, then the server passes the info to the remote device to run the job.

Take for instance, how the Nest thermostat works.  You can set the temperature in the app, which saves it on the server side.  The thermostat (remote device) polls the server to see if it needs to do anything, if so, the server passes the job to the thermostat.

Does anyone know what the communication protocol is that I should be searching for?  ...or maybe even the query I should kick off on Google?

Ideally, something in Python or Ruby would be nice (since that's what I know), but I'm cool with learning something new too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The high level description of an API to do this would be that of *three* endpoints; one that creates jobs and one that consumes jobs and one that marks jobs a completed.

Create a new Job

```
POST service.yoursite.com/jobs
  # authentication data
  # job data
```

Return all of the un-started or timed-out jobs.
(mark them as started)

```
GET service.yoursite.com/jobs
  # authentication data
```

Complete a job

```
PUT service.yoursite.com/jobs/:id
  # authentication data
  # job completion data
```

You can poll the endpoint that returns the jobs every so often